# Why is this dictionary comprehension so slow? Please suggest way to speed it up

Tags: python, pandas, list, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Hi Please help me either: speed up this dictionary compression; offer a better way to do it or gain a higher understanding of why it is so slow internally (like for example is calculation slowing down as the dictionary grows in memory size). I'm sure there must be a quicker way without learning some C!

`classes = {i : [1 if x in df['column'].str.split("|")[i] else 0 for x in df['column']] for i in df.index}`

with the output:
`{1:[0,1,0...0],......, 4000:[0,1,1...0]}`

from a df like this:

```
data_ = {'drugbank_id': ['DB06605', 'DB06606', 'DB06607', 'DB06608', 'DB06609'], 
         'drug-interactions': ['DB06605|DB06695|DB01254|DB01609|DB01586|DB0212',
                               'DB06605|DB06695|DB01254|DB01609|DB01586|DB0212', 
                               'DB06606|DB06607|DB06608|DB06609', 
                               'DB06606|DB06607', 
                               'DB06608']
                             }

pd.DataFrame(data = data_  , index=range(0,5) )
```

I am preforming it in a df with 4000 rows, the column df['column'] contains a string of Ids separated by |. The number of IDs in each row that needs splitting varies from 1 to 1000, however, this is done for all 4000 indexes. I tested it on the head of the df and it seemed quick enough, now the comprehension has been running for 24hrs. So maybe it is just the sheer size of the job, but feel like I could speed it up and at this point I want to stop it an re-engineer, however, I am scared that will set me back without much increase in speed, so before I do that wanted to get some thoughts, ideas and suggestions.

Beyond 4000x4000 size I suspect that using the Series and Index Objects is the another problem and that I would be better off using lists, but given the size of the task I am not sure how much speed that will gain and  maybe I am better off using some other method such as pd.apply(df, f(write line by line to json)). I am not sure - any help and education appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are unnecessarily string splitting the **entire column** on every iteration.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your expected output? I'm positive you can get a solution that will make this only take seconds, maybe a minute at most.

Comment: why are you "preforming" "a df" that "contains a string of Ids"?  why not just use a `set` or some other more appropriate data structure?   waiting 24 hours indicates you're doing something very wrong!  4k video is more than half as many pixels as all your data and playing a video means processing frames 30 times per second.   you should be able to get Python within 100x of this relatively easily, i.e. as @ALollz says a few seconds shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @ALollz thanks I added some example data. argh ok thanks haha i didnt realise that but it makes sense,  so do I need to split at cell level using df.iloc[df.index == i].str.split(). Haha a minute would be sweet

Comment: @SamMason Thanks, maybe inexperience I suppose. I will keep your 4K analogy in mind. it was still going after 3 hrs and so just left it overnight and its still not done. The id's correspond to a the ids that interact with the given id, they will be unique but in the df cell they are a string currently. Do you think i should do this outside of the df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col': ['1|2', '1|2|3', '2|3', '1|4']})

# split on '|' to convert string to list
df['col'] = df['col'].str.split('|')

# explode to get one row for each list element
df = df.explode('col')

# create dummy ID (this will become True in the final result)
df['dummy'] = 1

# use pivot to create dense matrix
df = (df.pivot(index='idx', columns='col', values='dummy')
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int))

# convert each row to a list
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.to_list(), axis=1)
print(df)

col  1  2  3  4          test
idx                          
1    1  1  0  0  [1, 1, 0, 0]
2    1  1  1  0  [1, 1, 1, 0]
3    0  1  1  0  [0, 1, 1, 0]
4    1  0  0  1  [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I like the way you've done this, makes everything very clear with the matrix/df showing all the values.  I added df.reset_index(inplace=True) and 
df['test'].to_dict() to get it in format needed. Will run it on the big data set shortly, just waiting for notebook to stop.cheers

Answer (score 2):

The output you want can be achieved using `dummies`. We split the column, `stack`, and use `max` to turn it into dummy indicators based on the original index. Then we use `reindex` to get it in the order you want based on the `'drugbank_id'` column.

Finally to get the dictionary you want we will transpose and use `to_dict`

```
classes = (pd.get_dummies(df['drug-interactions'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack())
             .max(level=0)
             .reindex(df['drugbank_id'], axis=1)
             .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
             .T.to_dict('list'))

print(classes)
{0: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],  #Has DB06605, No DB06606, No DB06607, No DB06608, No DB06609
 1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 2: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 3: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 4: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}
```

Comment: Thanks @ALollz,  working fine on the dummy data but when I try it on the actual df get an error ending as follows, any ideas on this? I cython_operation(self, kind, values, how, axis, min_count, **kwargs)
    491             # we use iNaT for the missing value on ints
    492             # so pre-convert to guard this condition
--> 493             if (values == iNaT).any():
    494                 values = ensure_float64(values)
    495             else:

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Comment: @ sorry saved before finishing

Comment: last traceback is: cython_operation(self, kind, values, how, axis, min_count, **kwargs)
    491             # we use iNaT for the missing value on ints
    492             # so pre-convert to guard this condition
--> 493             if (values == iNaT).any():
    494                 values = ensure_float64(values)
    495             else:

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Comment: sorry i suppose that isn't helpful - should I add the full traceback to my question?

Comment: No I wouldn't worry about that, unless you have a full example from start to finish with my code that would indicate that issue. It's quite an odd issue I've never come across it, what version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: Its the latest version 1.1.0 and error starts at line2 :  .max(level=0). I will downgrade pandas and see what happens

Comment: gone back to 0.25.3 seems its running now but not finished running yet

Comment: Yeah the `transpose` might take a while. You can comment out a few parts just to see where the real slowdown is. Weird it worked for me in 1.1 but perhpas there's some minor difference with the real data.

Comment: Thats good to know, not a bug then. yeah I was thinking it might be something with the data, will let you know how it goes. cheers